# Finding the total stock amount of a product across all stores

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Shop` model and a `Product` model. I also have a `StockItem` model which joins the two - `StockItem` has `shop_id`, `product_id` and `quantity` attributes.

I need to find the total quantity of each product in stock across all the shops and the way I'm doing this at the moment feels a bit clunky:

```
quantity = 0
Product.first.stock_items.collect { |si| quantity += si.quantity }
```

Can anyone suggest a more succinct method please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may count the total quantity for all products using one database query.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops, :through => :stock_items
  has_many :stock_items
  scope :with_total, :select => '[products].id, [products].name, sum([si].quantity) as total', 
    :joins => "left outer join stock_items [si] on [si].product_id = [products].id",
    :group => "[products].id, [products].name"  
end
```

Now you can get the total with this:

```
Product.with_total.first.total
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Product.first.stock_items.count
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for - it will return the number of Shops which carry the Product rather than the quantity each one has in stock.